# List a current posts' taxonomy tags in a widget in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, tags, widget, taxonomy

I would very much like to know if there is a widget that exists that would let me show the current page's associated taxonomy terms (preferably hierarchically) in a widget.

For example, if the current post has a Taxonomy term "Tom Hanks" in the Taxonomy of "Actor", the widget would list "Actor" then "Tom Hanks".  Even though there are many other actors in the taxonomy of "Actors", only the ones from the current page, are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking for a widget, you should ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

If you are writing your own widget and want help, show us the code and ask a specific question. SO is for programming Q&A.

Comment: Oh sorry - i may be back here again then if I can't find an existing one. Thanks for letting me know!